# Select three choices (multiple choices) in C

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, math

Hi I am working on a calculator and I have choices on what to solve. First, you will be asked how many given you have. For this code, I just made 3 given. So by default, input 3. Next, I have a list of 11 given in order to solve all the equations. The user will chose 3 numbers from 1-11... I have started a case using number 1,3,9 and 1,3,10, and 1,3,11. So my problem is that when I choose 1,3,10 randomly, for example I change the order in my input in the choice,choice2,choice 3 by choosing 3,10,1 instead of 1,3,10...

So let's say I will choose 1,3,10 but I inputted it in this order... 10,3,1.. but still must go to the action that it will implement.

I used the following line for my if statement...
if(choice==1,3,10 && choice2==1,3,10 &7 choice3==1,3,10) then execute action...

and

if( (choice== 1 || 3 || 10) && (choice2== 1 || 3 || 10) && (choice3== 1 || 3 || 10)) then execute action...

I've tried those above but it won't execute the statements below it... But it will execute the one above...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define PI 3.14159265

int main(){

double length, angle, radius, tangent, chord, midordinate, external, degree;
double pcurve,ptan,pintersect;
double ulength, udegree, uangle, uradius, utangent, uchord, umidordinate, uexternal;
int choice, choice2, choice3, given;

//For sin, cos, tan
double x, ret, val;
val = PI / 180;

printf("Enter number of given: ");
scanf("%d",&given);

if(given==3){
        choice:
        printf("[1]   -  Angle\n");
        printf("[2]   -  Degree\n");

        printf("[3]   -  Radius\n");
        printf("[4]   -  Length of Curve\n");           
        printf("[5]   -  Tangent\n");
        printf("[6]   -  Chord\n");
        printf("[7]   -  Midordinate\n");
        printf("[8]   -  External Distance\n");

        printf("[9]   -  Point of Intersection\n");
        printf("[10]  -  Point of Curve\n");
        printf("[11]  -  Point of Tangent\n");

printf("\n");

printf("Enter 1st given: ");
scanf("%d",&choice);

printf("Enter 2nd given: ");
scanf("%d",&choice2);   

printf("Enter 3rd given: ");
scanf("%d",&choice3);

printf("\n-----------------------------------\n");

if(choice==1,3,9 && choice2==1,3,9 && choice3==1,3,9){
        printf("Enter angle: ");
        scanf("%lf",&angle);

        printf("Enter radius: ");
        scanf("%lf",&radius);

        printf("Enter Point of Intersection (Point of Curve Value): ");
        scanf("%lf",&pcurve);

        printf("Enter Point of Intersection (Tangent Value): ");
        scanf("%lf",&tangent);

        printf("-----------------------------------\n");
        printf("\nGIVEN:\n");
        printf("-----------------------------------\n");
        printf("Angle = %lf\n",angle);
        printf("Radius = %lf\n",radius);
        printf("Point of Intersection (PI) = %lf + %lf\n", pcurve,tangent);

        uangle = angle/2;

        printf("-----------------------------------\n");
        printf("\nRESULTS:\n");
        printf("-----------------------------------\n");
        length=(radius*angle*PI)/180;
        tangent = radius * (tan(uangle*val));
        chord = 2*radius*(sin(uangle*val)); 
        midordinate = radius - (radius*(cos(uangle*val)));
        external = radius *( (1/(cos (uangle*val) ) ) - 1 ) ;   
        pintersect = pcurve + tangent;
        pcurve = pintersect - tangent;
        ptan = pcurve + length;

        printf("Radius = %lf\n",radius);
        printf("Length of Curve = %lf\n",length);
        printf("Tangent = %lf\n",tangent);
        printf("Chord = %lf\n",chord);
        printf("Mid Ordinate = %lf\n",midordinate);
        printf("External Distance = %lf\n",external);
        printf("Point of Intersection = %lf\n",pintersect);
        printf("Point of Curve = %lf\n",pcurve);
        printf("Point of Tangent = %lf\n",ptan);

}

else

if( (choice== 1 || 3 || 10) && (choice2== 1 || 3 || 10) && (choice3== 1 || 3 || 10)){
        printf("Enter angle: ");
        scanf("%lf",&angle);

        printf("Enter radius: ");
        scanf("%lf",&radius);

        printf("Enter Point of Curve (Point of Intersection Value): ");
        scanf("%lf",&pintersect);

        printf("Enter Point of Curve (Tangent Value): ");
        scanf("%lf",&tangent);

        printf("-----------------------------------\n");
        printf("\nGIVEN:\n");
        printf("-----------------------------------\n");
        printf("Angle = %lf\n",angle);
        printf("Radius = %lf\n",radius);
        printf("Point of Curve (PC) = %lf - %lf\n", pintersect,tangent);

        uangle = angle/2;

        printf("-----------------------------------\n");
        printf("\nRESULTS:\n");
        printf("-----------------------------------\n");
        length=(radius*angle*PI)/180;
        tangent = radius * (tan(uangle*val));
        chord = 2*radius*(sin(uangle*val)); 
        midordinate = radius - (radius*(cos(uangle*val)));
        external = radius *( (1/(cos (uangle*val) ) ) - 1 ) ;   
        pintersect = pcurve + tangent;
        pcurve = pintersect - tangent;
        ptan = pcurve + length;

        printf("Radius = %lf\n",radius);
        printf("Length of Curve = %lf\n",length);
        printf("Tangent = %lf\n",tangent);
        printf("Chord = %lf\n",chord);
        printf("Mid Ordinate = %lf\n",midordinate);
        printf("External Distance = %lf\n",external);
        printf("Point of Intersection = %lf\n",pintersect);
        printf("Point of Curve = %lf\n",pcurve);
        printf("Point of Tangent = %lf\n",ptan);

}

if(choice==1,3,11 && choice2==1,3,11 && choice3==1,3,11){
        printf("Enter angle: ");
        scanf("%lf",&angle);

        printf("Enter radius: ");
        scanf("%lf",&radius);

        printf("Enter Point of Tangent (Point of Curve Value): ");
        scanf("%lf",&pintersect);

        printf("Enter Point of Tangent (Length Value): ");
        scanf("%lf",&length);

        printf("-----------------------------------\n");
        printf("\nGIVEN:\n");
        printf("-----------------------------------\n");
        printf("Angle = %lf\n",angle);
        printf("Radius = %lf\n",radius);
        printf("Point of Curve (PC) = %lf + %lf\n", pcurve,length);

        uangle = angle/2;

        printf("-----------------------------------\n");
        printf("\nRESULTS:\n");
        printf("-----------------------------------\n");
        length=(radius*angle*PI)/180;
        tangent = radius * (tan(uangle*val));
        chord = 2*radius*(sin(uangle*val)); 
        midordinate = radius - (radius*(cos(uangle*val)));
        external = radius *( (1/(cos (uangle*val) ) ) - 1 ) ;   
        pintersect = pcurve + tangent;
        pcurve = pintersect - tangent;
        ptan = pcurve + length;

        printf("Radius = %lf\n",radius);
        printf("Length of Curve = %lf\n",length);
        printf("Tangent = %lf\n",tangent);
        printf("Chord = %lf\n",chord);
        printf("Mid Ordinate = %lf\n",midordinate);
        printf("External Distance = %lf\n",external);
        printf("Point of Intersection = %lf\n",pintersect);
        printf("Point of Curve = %lf\n",pcurve);
        printf("Point of Tangent = %lf\n",ptan);

}




}


getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the C/C++ syntax *that* obtuse ? In short : you need `if(stuff == a || stuff == b || stuff == c)`. Also, for your next question, please make sure to craft a minimal example. All of these `printf()`'s are unrelated to the question.

Comment: `choice== 1 || 3 || 10` evals to `true`. you shall grab a textbook first.

Comment: Change you code from `choice=1,3,10` to `choice== 1 || choice == 3 || choice == 10`

Comment: @SatishChalasani So what if I shuffle the order? If I input... 3 10 1 instead of 1 3 10... Wasn't able to execute the whats inside of its if statement...

Comment: That is quite probably the most horrible indenting I have seen for years  `choice=1,3,10` assigns one to choice, throws away the 3, and returns 10 as a value which is unlikley to be what you want

Comment: Your whole approach is wrong.  The details are also wrong (the , operator does not mean anything similar to what you have assumed).  But you should fix the basic design before revisiting any question of syntax details.  You need to use a lot more thought and less code.  Good programming involves generalizing related situations so they can share common code, NOT individually detecting and handling each unique situation.

Comment: In this case, order in the if statement doesn't not matter. both the statements ` if(choice == 3 || choice == 1||  choice == 10 )' and `if( choice == 10 || choice == 1 || choice == 3 )' are same.

Comment: @SatishChalasani However the user does have to do that test for all 3 of choice1, choice2, choice3

Comment: @TomTanner yes user has to do that. I dont disagree with that.

Comment: I have many cases to be followed... So I just showed here the case for choosing 1,3,9 or 1,3,10 or 1,3,11 each of the three has different equations to be solved inside their if statement... If I choose 1 and 3 and 10 together, then it will execute its statement. If I choose 1 and 3 and 11 then it will execute a different one. So, my problem is what if I input 3, 10, 1 instead of 1,3,10 because the code I have is if(choice==1 && choice2= 3 && choice3==10)

Comment: @Quentin Tried using switch but... I will be repeating case 1 all over... because i have a combination of 1 3 9, 1 3 10, and 1 3 11

Comment: @user3767918 In the case of switch, you can have  nested switches. With switch, code looks much better and eliminate redundant lines.

Comment: @user3767918 I'm having a really hard time making sense of your question, but from what I gathered that question is indeed not a duplicate of this one. Vote retracted. Could you perhaps rework your question to be clearer, possibly by summarizing your goal, then providing an example ?

Comment: @user3767918 You can put all your print statements in a method call print output. Call this method whereever you wanted to print.

Comment: Thank you all. Now I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(choice==1,3,9 && choice2==1,3,9 && choice3==1,3,9){

if( (choice== 1 || 3 || 10) && (choice2== 1 || 3 || 10) && (choice3== 1 || 3 || 10))  //always TRUE

if(choice==1,3,11 && choice2==1,3,11 && choice3==1,3,11){
```

Do you consider these conditions as valid syntax to behave as your needs ?

Correct would be

```
if((choice==1 ||choice==3 ||choice==9) && (choice2==1 ||choice2==3 ||choice2==9) && (choice3==1 ||choice3==3 ||choice3==9))

if((choice==1 ||choice==3 ||choice==10) && (choice2==1 ||choice2==3 ||choice2==10) && (choice3==1 ||choice3==3 ||choice3==10))

if((choice==1 ||choice==3 ||choice==11) && (choice2==1 ||choice2==3 ||choice2==11) && (choice3==1 ||choice3==3 ||choice3==11))
```

Comment: Thanks! I finally understand. The if statement conditions you made is very clear. Why wasn't I able to think of this solution. I was stuck with the idea of having if((choice==1 ||choice2==3 ||choice3==9) && (choice==1 ||choice2==3 ||choice3==9) && (choice==1 ||choice2==3 ||choice3==9)) And I am sorry for my question if it's too complicated or not worthy to be posted here. But really am thankful with all of your answers. And Ive learned something now.

Comment: @user3767918  You are welcome . Please use correct and clear statements to avoid confusion .

Comment: Setting aside the fact that the basic design ought to be better, you still should not use `if((choice==1 ||choice==3 ||choice==9) && (choice2==1 ||choice2==3 ||choice2==9) && (choice3==1 ||choice3==3 ||choice3==9))` but instead use `if((choice==1 ||choice2==1 ||choice3==1) && (choice==3 ||choice2==3 ||choice3==3) && (choice==9 ||choice2==9 ||choice3==9))` Think through how that is different and it may give you insight into why the second form is safer, as well as insight into related issues in your design.

Comment: @JSF yea second statement will eliminate the chance of all three same numbers .